# Acessar um arquivo usando Properties

Tags: java, classes, matriz, propriedade

Estou trabalhando com um método que recebe como argumento um objeto da classe Properties:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Properties props = new Properties();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("TREINAMENTO.txt", "E:\\USER\\Documents\\Interface");

    }
```

No método setup, tenho:

```
public void setUp(Properties props) {


        props.getProperty("TREINAMENTO.txt", "E:\\USER\\Documents\\Interface");

        }
```

Eu preciso acessar o arquivo TREINAMENTO.txt, que tem o formato de uma matriz de double, e colocar ela numa variável treinamento[][]. Como posso fazer isso? Não entendi bem o funcionamento da classe Properties.

Answer (score 1):

`Properties`, são arquivos de configuração que trabalham com pares de `chave` e `valor` - essas chaves e valores são sempre `Strings`.

Você utiliza a `chave` para recuperar o `valor` que você guardar nesse arquivo de configuração.

Veja um exemplo de como ler o seu arquivo (coloque ele na sua pasta de projeto):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class LerPropriedades {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("TREINAMENTO.txt");
        Properties propriedades = new Properties();
        propriedades.load(in);
        in.close();

        for(String chave : propriedades.stringPropertyNames()) {
              String valor = propriedades.getProperty(chave);
              System.out.println(chave + ": " + valor);
            }
    }
}
```

Você pode também experimentar criar um arquivo de propriedades para ver como ele deve ser estruturado, desta forma:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SalvarProperties {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties propriedades = new Properties();

        propriedades.setProperty("0", "1.14");
        propriedades.setProperty("1", "132.495");

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TREINAMENTO.txt");
        propriedades.store(out, "---comentario---");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Se você quiser colocar as informações lidas num `array`, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira (desculpe, não sei fazer melhor):

```
Double meuArray[][] = new Double[10][2];
int counter = 0;

for(String chave : propriedades.stringPropertyNames()) {
    String valor = propriedades.getProperty(chave);
    meuArray[counter][0] = Double.parseDouble(chave);
    meuArray[counter][1] = Double.parseDouble(valor);
    counter++;
}
```

Só substituir o loop `for` do `LerPropriedades` por esse código. Eu usei o seguinte arquivo para testar:

```
#TREINAMENTO
#25/05/2017
0=2.43
1=1.2343
2=15.32
3=80.55
4=532.0
5=943.1
6=9.0
7=3.00038
8=65.12
9=200.01
```

[Veja aqui mais informações](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Comment: Mas uma coisa eu não entendi bem, Daniel: no meu caso, a matriz tem 1000 linhas e 20 colunas, eu precisaria iniciar um arquivo pra cada coluna?  Porque, pelo que entendi, o meuArray precisa da coluna de valores e a coluna de chaves...

Comment: @donut Você quer dizer algo como uma chave para 20 valores? Você pode usar algum separador nos valores, por exemplo vírgula, e salvar eles assim: 0=1.32,2.54,17.12,80.1 - depois na hora de ler você separa eles de novo - e assim você mantém um único arquivo.

Comment: @donut Mas eu tinha entendido que você já tinha um arquivo pra ler - qual é a estrutura dele? Para ler ele como `Properties` ele meio que obrigatoriamente tem que estar estruturado como chaves e valores... :o

Comment: Ele possui valores separados por espaço, como por exemplo                             0.28 1.36 4.24 8.66                                                                                                       1.41 1.71 6.99 12.5                                                                                                 Nesse caso, eu devo inserir um separador, como ponto-vírgula, no próprio arquivo?? No exemplo que vc deu, a chave 0 está associada à linha 1.32,2.54,17.12,80.1??

Comment: @donut Se você **já tem** um arquivo com 1000 linhas, talvez você não consiga abri-lo da maneira como eu indiquei - pq. o programa espera a estrutura correta (você chegou a tentar?) - e eu acho que não faz sentido você alterar o seu arquivo de texto para ficar "compatível" com `Properties` - faz mais sentido ler o arquivo e descobrir uma maneira de transformá-lo em properties dentro do programa. Pode ser interessante você [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/207367/edit) sua pergunta, e incluir mais informações - inclusive trechos do seu arquivo, se possível.

Comment: @donut Sim, no caso a chave 0 estaria associada a linha inteira - mas no seu exemplo, eu não entendi onde está a chave - são só números corridos separados por espaço?