# Strings em JAVA

Tags: java, string

Uma vez trabalhei com um programa onde tinha um arquivo txt com todos valores de Strings e no código eu apenas referenciava, logo todo lugar que eu usava a mesma string eu só precisava alterar no txt e ainda não havia problema usar acentos ou caracteres especiais `(@, #, %, *)`

Estou utilizando IDE Eclipse, não sei se muda alguma coisa...

Um exemplo, quando crio um `JLabel` e quero definir o texto dele eu usava:

```
myLabel.setText("arquivotxt.mystrings.boasvindas");
```

E no arquivo txt tinha a linha:

```
arquivotxt.mystrings.boasvindas = "Bem vindos!"
```

Alguém faz ideia do que estou falando? Pois estou precisando para deixar meu programa melhor...

Comment: Você já não fez essa pergunta no sabado? Sugiro que visite **[ask]** para aprender a como fazer uma pergunta aqui e leia [que tipo de perguntas deve evitar fazer no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: fiz a pergunta muito mal formulada, apaguei alguns minutos depois, pois a pergunta foi recusada também e como estava cansado deixei para continuar meu programa hoje...

Comment: Está mexendo com a API swing?

Comment: Estou usando swing sim!

Comment: Então o que você procura é manuseio por arquivo properties, veja essa resposta: [Acessar um arquivo usando Properties](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207375/28595)

Comment: Outra resposta que vai lhe ajudar: [Internacionalização em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150626/28595)

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso, vlw